# Panda's equivalent of R's order() for arranging dataframe columns

Tags: python, r, pandas

I'm learning pandas after using R for several years. I would like to arrange the order of columns in a data frame based on the max value in the column. What is the equivalent in pandas of the R example code below?

```
# R code
test = data.frame(matrix(1:9,ncol = 3))
test[,order(apply(test, 2, max),decreasing = TRUE)]
```

Here's what I've attempted unsuccessfully in pandas:

```
# Python code
test = pd.DataFrame({"c":[1,2,3],
                     "a":[4,5,6],
                     "t":[7,8,9]})
test = test.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
```

Obviously, that just arranges them columns based on the name. I used c, a, t to check for that behavior. How can I replicate what I did in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more succinct version, but here's one option:

```
test[test.max(columns=1).order(ascending=False).index]
```

- `test.max(columns=1)` finds the max in each column (like R's `apply(test, 2, max)`)
- `.order(ascending=False).index` is like R's `order(,,, decreasing=T)`
- `test[ column_numbers ]` reorders the columns.

Comment: Good answer with one small update: as of pandas 0.24.2 `pandas.Series.order()` [has been deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.order.html). You can achieve the same effect of R's `order()` by using `pandas.Series.sort_values().index` now, i.e. returning the index of the sorted Series.